# CRM 2011 LINQ invalid 'where' condition when using logicalname

Tags: linq, where-clause, crm

Obvious attempt here is to get phone calls by a specific account ID, and ONLY phonecalls which have a regardingobject type of "account" (this is only a basic part of the full call, but even this fails).

```
var linqPhonecalls = from pc in svcContext.PhoneCallSet
     where ((pc.RegardingObjectId.Id == account.Id) && (pc.RegardingObjectId.LogicalName == "account"))
     select new
     {
         subj = pc.Subject,
         stateCD = pc.StateCode,
     };
```

Through research on the net I ran into this idea ( http://informeddynamicscrm.blogspot.com/2012/01/linq-restrictions-with-crm-2011-xrm.html ) and tried the following:

```
pc.RegardingObjectId.LogicalName.Equals("account") == true
```

As well as using Contains() and any other comparison operations I could try.  It seems like the major problem here is the use of .LogicalName (also tried .Name)

Because I can't get it to work, I'm going to leave that check out of the equation for now, but I'd really like to put it in there because I'm going to be joining against other regarding types and want to sort things out.

Comment: How does it fail?  An exception or doesn't filter correctly?  Can you give some example data?

Comment: It says "Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method."

The data doesn't matter, it's the fact that when any type of compare is performed on the LogicalName in the where clause, it fails.